# Virtually defragment a fragmented memory as if it was contiguous in c++

Tags: c++, memory, c++17

is there a way or is it possible to take e.g 10 memory regions (e.g. pointers with given size) and create a sort of overlay such that they can be handled/treated as contiguous?

The use case would be something like reconstruct a message out of "n" frames without copying them around.
Of course the "n" frames are appended/prependend with a header which should be stripped in order to reconstruct the information. Moreover a variable could be e.g. splitted across two consecutive frames.

Few more details for future help.

Otter solution is quite nice but it lacks the possibility to lay a structure on top of multiple boost::join-ed block.
Of course a std::copy of the joined block will create a contiguous copy of all the interested and fragmented regions but in my case i would like it to be "virtual" due to performance constraints.

Regards,

Comment: Couldn't you allocate one BIG region for the 10 to be drawn from?  Then you can do whatever you want to them.

Comment: `std::deque` and `std::list` already do this internally, so clearly it can be done.  Also the STL `rope` class.

Comment: The data is contained and parsed from a file using a shared_mmap_source from boost. The issue again is that there are headers and other stuff in between so ideally i would just want to identify certain offset and somehow map it to a contiguous region via a struct pointer for example

Comment: What you are looking for is to write your own memory allocator or memory pool.

Comment: Yes but the memory is already allocated. It is like using e.g. fread and have already the address to where the data starts since the file has been loaded in the RAM. Moreover one needs to parse the file to understand which segment is important for reconstructing the information

Comment: I got a start, something vaguely like this https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1142b82197a0805d (does not compile, I ran out of time)

Comment: You can get range/iterator interface for several ranges by using `boost::range::join`.

Comment: I like the idea but do you think it is feasible for memory regions? I mean you are using "," as way to join things but i would rather have bytes joining them together without any separator. Something like joined_data = join(0x12355, 0x23456, 0x86435) and joined data is just pointing to the 3 addresses making the contiguous once e.g you say joined[12356] or something like this

Comment: actually casting the region would be even better e.g auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<struct>(joined)

Answer (score 2):

`boost::range::join` is a great helper here - [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html). When working with random access ranges it will also produce random access range with quick access to elements. As the manual tells `The resultant range will have the lowest common traversal of the two ranges supplied as parameters`

Also when working with plain memory `boost::make_iterator_range` cound help.

Take a look at this short example.

```
int arr1[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };   // let's join these 3 plain memory arrays
int arr2[] = { 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int arr3[] = { 10, 11, 12};

int* mem1 = arr1;  // let's make the example more complicated 
int* mem2 = arr2;  // because int arr1[] with known size will be recognized 
int* mem3 = arr3;  // as a range by boost::join

auto res1 = boost::range::join(boost::make_iterator_range(mem1, mem1 + 6),
    boost::make_iterator_range(mem2, mem2 + 4));    // join 2 ranges by pointer arithmetics
auto res2 = boost::range::join(res1,                // join previously joined range
    boost::make_iterator_range(mem3, mem3 + 3));

for (auto& r : res2)        // the resulted range is iterable
{
    std::cout << r << "\n";
}
std::cout << res2[12];      // outputs '12', note that this result
                            // was eventually got by pointer arithmetics
                            // applyed to mem3
```

Comment: Nice. What happens to res2 exactly? is it a copy or just a wrapper that points around when asked?

Comment: If i do auto test_s = reinterpret_cast<const test*>(&res2[0]); std::cout << test_s->a; (a is uint32_t) the value is 1 but it should be 3210. So how would i lay a known structure on top of it now?

Comment: @Luigi It is a wrapper. No copies are made.

Comment: @Luigi If the original data is an array of `test` structs than you should `make_iterator_range` with a pointer to `test`. Like so: `test* mem1 = ...; auto res = boost::range::join(boost::make_iterator_range(mem1, mem1 + no_of_test_structs), ...); test* test = &res[0];`

Comment: the original data put together (so defragmented) will compose a single test struct. So multiple frames (in you example mem1, mem2 e.g. uint8_t pointers) will compose an information (struct test) when put together

Comment: I realized what you are willing to achieve. Unfortunately it's not possible with this method. This method does not provide contiguous memory to lay c-structures on. And I'm afraid there is no such method.

Comment: The only thing you can do is gathering all memory blocks into one contiguous block.This gathering can be done by simple std::copy of boost::range::join object.